# How to check whether admin or user is logged in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

Currently i am developing a module in odoo. In my module users can edit there own data only, but admin can do anything. But with my code admin also can't edit. If i know admin is logged in, then i can bypass admin account. So how to know when admin is logged in?

```
def write(self, vals):
    //if admin is logged in i need to bypass the below code//
    if self.create_uid != self.env.user:
        raise Warning('You can not able to edit this document as this is not your record')
    return super(request_room, self).write(vals)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use the super_user (admin) id.
Probably the id = 1
The code below would do the trick.

```
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID
def write(self, vals):
    //if admin is logged in i need to bypass the below code//
    if self.create_uid != self.env.user and self.create_uid != SUPERUSER_ID:
        raise Warning('You can not able to edit this document as this is not your record')
    return super(request_room, self).write(vals)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hear You can directly go to the below way

```
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID
def write(self, vals):
    //if admin is logged in i need to bypass the below code//
    if self.env.user.id != SUPERUSER_ID:
        raise Warning('You can not able to edit this document as this is not your record')
    return super(request_room, self).write(vals)
```

**SUPERUSER_ID :** static hard coded ID for the admin user

**self.env.user :** which gives us for current user ID of the self instance

I hope my answer may help you :)

Answer (score 1):

To archive this you have to use SUPERUSER_ID,

and you also can prevent by using id "1" because in our system admin user have 1 id,but SUPERUSER_ID is good solution.

from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID